# Find_package() unable to find packages that I've created in the workspace

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having a weird issue where I get the following error.

```
  Project 'gimbal_control' tried to find library 'mav_recv'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'mav_recv'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing
  its code is included?
```

When the existing ROS packages i.e. roscpp / nodelet that are in the find_library() function work fine. However when I include my package such as mav_recv or gstreamer_udp, it gives me the following error. The other 2 packages that are independent, build just fine by themselves. However, this package that is reliant on mav_recv messages gives me that cmake error. It seems that the find_library() function is unable to locate my packages in the current workspace, while it does find packages in the ROS workspace (I've installed ROS from source in ros_catkin_ws).

I've included both ROS workspaces in the /.bashrc file. And ROS is able to run the gstreamer_udp and mav_recv nodes when built individually. Here is my CMakeLists.txt for mav_recv,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mav_recv)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp message_generation)

add_message_files(
    FILES
    Camera_mode.msg
    Gimbal_commands.msg
)

generate_messages()

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp message_runtime
)

include_directories(include
                    # For mavlink messages
                    /home/pi/mavlink/include/uwa_grand_challenge
                    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(mav_recv_node src/mav_recv_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(mav_recv_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_library(mav_recv_lib src/mav_recv.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    mav_recv_node
    mav_recv_lib
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

and gimbal_control CMakeLists.txt,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gimbal_control)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp mav_recv)

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp mav_recv
)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(gimbal_control_node src/gimbal_control_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(gimbal_control_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_library(gimbal_control_lib src/gimbal_control.cpp src/i2c_bus.cpp)
add_dependencies(gimbal_control_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(
    gimbal_control_node
    gimbal_control_lib
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Any help would really be appreciated as I've spent a long time on trying to get it to work.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336841/find_package()-unable-to-find-packages-that-i%27ve-created-in-the-workspace./) by [manu-adina](https://answers.ros.org/users/46208/manu-adina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have this in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
[..]

project(mav_recv)

[..]

catkin_package(
    [..]
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    [..]
)

[..]

add_library(mav_recv_lib src/mav_recv.cpp)

[..]
```

Note how you export a library target with `LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}` (where `${PROJECT_NAME}` would be replaced with `mav_recv`), but then don't actually have any library target with that name.

The only library you create in this build script is `mav_recv_lib`.

You'll either have to change the name of the library to `${PROJECT_NAME}`, or change the exported target name to `mav_recv_lib`.

So this should work (for `mav_recv`, but it would be similar for your other package):

```
catkin_package(
    [..]
    LIBRARIES mav_recv_lib
    [..]
)
```

Note that `gimbal_control` has the exact same problem.

You may be interested in [fkie/catkin_lint](https://github.com/fkie/catkin_lint) which is a tool capable of parsing your package manifests and build scripts and checking them for common errors and bad practices.

Finally:

> It seems that the find_library() function is unable to locate my packages in the current workspace, while it does find packages in the ROS workspace (I've installed ROS from source in ros_catkin_ws).

> I've included both ROS workspaces in the /.bashrc file.

Please be aware that `source`ing multiple workspaces may not do what you expect, as by default, `source`ing a second workspace will overwrite the environment variables of the first. If `ros_catkin_ws` is actually an [underlay](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying), then it would work, but in that case there would be no need to `source` `ros_catkin_ws`, as it would be automatically `source`d as part of your "current workspace".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manu-adina](https://answers.ros.org/users/46208/manu-adina/) on 2019-11-05**:
Thanks gvdhoorn! I've spent a lot of time trying to fix that error and couldn't even think that this part was the problem due to tutorials always having ${PROJECT_NAME} for the catkin_package libraries. I definitely need to spend more time on trying to understand CMake. Thanks again gvdhoorn!